# How to add WP7-Toolkit Feathereffect with C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to use the feather effect on some of my textblocks. It should look like this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Blacblabla" 
                Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0"/>
```

I create this textblock completely via C# and add it then `(bla.Children.add(textblock1))`.
How can I add the `toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex` to my textblock with c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try it, but

```
TurnstileFeatherEffect.SetFeatheringIndex(textblock1, featheringIndex);
```

should do the trick. `featheringIndex` is the index you want to set.

Comment: there exists this method (respect! only 1 google result for it) and i'm pretty sure it does what i asked for. it also looks like i have some other issues with animation, so i mark this as solution, but i am not 100% sure..

Comment: I just tested it and works, it sets the feathering index correctly.